# Do I need to use delete after pthread_mutex_destroy

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Suppose I use

```
pthread_mutex_t *m = new pthread_mutex_t;
pthread_mutex_init(m, NULL);
```

to initialize a mutex. Then after I'm done, and invoke pthread_mutex_destroy, do I need to use

```
delete m;
```

to release all resources?

Comment: Normally you don't dynamically allocate the mutex (`m`). The mutex is normally an object. You pass the address of the object so that the init function so that it can initialize it correctly. (which usually means dynamically allocating an object and putting the pointer into the location passed (there is a reason why othread_mutex_t is opaque)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to free the memory, as **`pthread_mutex_destroy` can't do it for you**.

Why doesn't pthread_mutex_destroy free the memory for you ? Because you are allowed to do this:

```
pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL);

pthread_mutex_destroy(&m); /* Can't free &m. */
```

You can try it using `valgrind`:

```
==836== LEAK SUMMARY:
==836==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Comment: I'm confused - does the code in the first block actually produce the output of valgrind? pthread_mutex_t is statically allocated, so where is the memory leaked?

Comment: @WayneUroda No, it's not the output from that code. It's the output from the OP's code. I was merely explaining why `pthread_mutex_destroy` can't free its parameter.

Comment: I accidentally find out that I asked such a basic question and did not accept the right answer *three years ago*. Maybe I had amnesia?

Answer (score 2):

Initialization of mutex using `pthread_mutex_init` is different aspect; and having memory allocated for the object (of type `pthread_mutex_t`) is different aspect.

Using *initialization* routine of some library is different than allocating memory for it on heap or on stack. It is like having a FILE* as local variable, and initializing the file-pointer using `fopen`